# calculating definite integral problem

Tags: integration

I know that...
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{(a^2+x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

$a\tan y=x$

$\frac{a}{\cos^2 y}dy=dx$

So,
$$I=\int\frac{a \hspace{0.1cm} dy}{\cos^2 y(a^2+a^2\tan^2 y)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

$$I=\int\frac{a \hspace{0.1cm} dy}{\cos^2 y \cdot a^3(1+\tan^2 y)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

$$I=\frac{1}{a^2} \int\frac{dy}{\cos^2 y\cdot\frac{1}{( \cos^2 y})^\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{a^2} \int\cos y \hspace{0.1cm}dy$$

$$I= \frac{1}{a^2} \sin y $$
$$I=\frac{1}{a^2} \sin({\arctan{\frac{x}{y}}})$$

$$I=\frac{1}{a^2} \cdot \frac{\frac{x}{a}}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{x}{a}})^2}$$
$$I=\frac{x}{a^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}+C$$

**How to calculate the following integral?**
$$-h\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{(x^2+h^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Comment: Integrate between $-A$ and $A$ for $A>0$ using the antiderivative you just found and take the limit $A\to\infty$.

Comment: Improper integral is well described topic in broad literature.  You may check this page: https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Mount_Royal_University/MATH_2200%3A_Calculus_for_Scientists_II/2%3A_Techniques_of_Integration/2.6%3A_Improper_Integrals

Comment: ummmm: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$ has limit $1$ as $x$ goes to $+ \infty$ but limit $-1$ as $x$ goes to $- \infty.$ Then you have an extra $a^2$  factor hanging around

Comment: For any $x\in R$, we have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, therefore for any $x>0, x=\sqrt{x^2}$, and $x<0, x= -\sqrt{x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
-h \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{\left(x^2+h^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = & -h \cdot \frac{1}{h^2}\left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{h^2+x^2}}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty} \\
= & -\frac{1}{h}\left[\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{h^2+x^2}}-\lim _{h \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{h^2+x^2}}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
For $x>0$, we have
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{h^2+x^2}}=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{h}{x}\right)^2+1}}=1
$$
For $x<0$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{h^2+x^2}} & =\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{h^2+x^2}}{x}} \\
& =\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{h^2+x^2}}{-\sqrt{x^2}}} \\
& =-\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{h}{x}\right)^2+1}} \\
& =-1
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$-h \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{\left(x^2+h^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} =-\frac{1}{h}(1-(-1))=-\frac{2}{h} $$
Wish it helps.